# Is it better to run a Ruby on Rails website on Heroku or on Amazon Webservices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services

Is it better to run a Ruby on Rails website on Heroku or on Amazon Webservices ?
We plan on using MySQL…

Not sure about how the prices compare, 
also about the actual experiences.

What advices do you have?

Thanks in advance!
C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on your needs and how much you are willing to spend. Heroku itself runs on top of AWS and provides a really nice platform on top of it (we call PaaS - platform as a service), hiding away from you many of the management tasks that you would have when managing your own servers in Amazon EC2.

On the other hand, you pay a price for it, which makes Heroku more expensive than EC2, especially if you will need to scale your app in the future. I never tried Heroku for a big app, but I suppose it gets expensive pretty fast. However, it is still an awesome plaform and would be a no brainer for me if money wasn't a concern. For small apps and for testing it is incredibly useful since you can get an app up and running in minutes and it is incredibly easy to scale and to install addons.

In EC2, you will have the management tasks of configuring your own servers, which can be a quite big amount of work as well. However, it is cheaper when compared to Heroku.

Anyways, as I said, there is no actual best option, but both have advantages and tradeoffs and are great services for what they are willing to offer!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is incredibly useful!